# What does nk means in line spacing?

Tags: style, formatting

I see in some journals that mention the line spacing in MS Word in terms of "nk".

What does that mean and how can I set that in the Word?

For example in [this link](http://www.jemsjournal.org/Default.aspx?p=Guide-for-Authors), it states:

> 2 nk spaces should be added before references and 3 nk spaces should
>   be added after.

Comment: The only Google results I get for "nk line spacing" seem to be for journals that accept submissions in both English and Turkish. I can only assume it's an abbreviation of something in Turkish, as it's certainly not a term I've heard in English, and I can't seem to find references to it elsewhere.

Comment: Some journals specify no kerning for submissions, although that would be *letter* spacing rather than *line* spacing. Could it refer to that?

Comment: You are correct. It is in the turkish journals but I can't find the meaning in turkish dictionaries! This is a bit weird! @F1Krazy

Comment: Thanks but I think it has not something to do with kerning. As you guessed the nk is a unit for line spacing and paragraph spacing. @motosubatsu

Comment: @motosubatsu No, it's definitely being used as a unit of measurement, I saw references to "6 nk". "6 no kerning" makes no sense.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could provide quotations and citations of where you are seeing this is "some journals".

Comment: @F1Krazy It makes sense if the 6 is the font size. If it is, 6nk would give a reasonable estimate of the characters-per-line.

Comment: An example is added @RayButterworth

Comment: I think this can not match with the example I added to the post! @WeckarE.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is a poor translation from Turkish. "nk" probably stands for line (nokta) - it seems obvious in context. The unit of measure has been generally obsolete since 1931.